# Verbatim Macro not expanded in htlatex

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

`verbatim` Text is not expanding when using `htlatex`. How to turned on?
My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\myverbtext#1{{\bfseries #1}}
\begin{document}
This is the sample paragraph.

\begin{verbatim}
This is the \myverbtext{verbatim} text.
\end{verbatim}

\begin{equation}
\alpha + \beta = \gamma
\end{equation}

\begin{verbatim}
\begin{equation}
\myverbtext{\rho} \alpha + \beta = \gamma
\end{equation}
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

My `tex4ht` command is:

`htlatex file.tex`

Comment: In verbatim mode *nothing* is expanded

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for your reply and it's possible any other way?

Comment: Please, be more specific about your aim.

Comment: @egreg: I would like to convert `LaTeX` to `DocX` Conversion for official usage. All the `LaTeX` equations should be convert to `MathType OLE Format`. So i have decided to use `htlatex` without LaTeX equations changing.

Comment: @Balaji you should try to convert the document to odt with `mk4ht oolatex` and then convert it to `docx` using LibreOffice or Pandoc, maybe.

Comment: @michal: I would like to convert all the equations should be `MathType OLE Format`. That is possible in `oolatex` and syntax please.

Comment: @Balaji I expect that it should be possible to convert the equations to Mathtype in Word, if you have Mathtype installed.

Comment: @michal: Yes. I have already installed `MathType` In `Word`. Could you please advise how do use `mk4ht oolatex`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What OP really wants is to convert LaTeX document with equations to `DOCX` format with math in Mathtype format. It is possible, but not straight forward, we need several conversion steps for best results:

1. compile the document to OpenDocument format

   mk4ht oolatex filename

result of the compilation is `filename.odt` file.

2. While current Word can open it, it is better to do some cleanup with LibreOffice, Word has sometimes problems with math in ODT produced by `tex4ht`. So open the `filename.odt` in LibreOffice and save it as `filename.docx`.
3. Open `filename.docx` in Word, and from `Mathtype` bookmark select `Convert Equations` button:

[image]

Select all equation types to convert and select the whole document:

[image]

All your equations should be converted to Mathtype now